# jQuery CSS put image over image with javascript event handlers

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make an image gallery where you have a thumb of the image, then when you hover over it a red X appears at the bottom right of the thumb.

If you click the thumb itself it will open a lightbox gallery.  If you click the red X image, it will delete the image.

I have that CSS setup fairly well, for now anyway.  It places the red X in the correct place over the image, and I have it's z set to like 20000.

The problem is no matter if I click the thumb or the x the lightbox fires.

Here is what we are looking at:

Some JS:

```
$('#PicturePreview a').lightBox();
$(document).delegate('.delete_img', 'click', function() {
    alert("You dirty rat");
            // I can't get it to get in here....
});
```

Some CSS:

```
.delete_img {
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 80px;
text-align: right;
width: 150px;
z-index: 2000000;
}
#PicturePreview img {
max-height: 120px;
max-width: 153px;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="PicturePreview">
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
        <div class='preview_image'>
        <a href='../../pic.jpg' alt='' />
                        <img src='../../pic.jpg' alt='' />
            <div class='delete_img'>
                            <img src='assets/common/red_x.png' alt='' />
                        </div>
        </a>
                </div>
    </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent anchor is overriding the event; try moving the delete_img div outside of it like this:

```
<div class='preview_image'>
    <div class='delete_img'>
        <img src='assets/common/red_x.png' alt='' />
    </div>    
    <a href='../../pic.jpg' alt=''>
        <img src='../../pic.jpg' alt='' />
    </a>
</div>
```

Depending on your CSS, you may need to set the preview_image div to `position: relative` to keep the red x aligned to the preview image.

Comment: @guyfromfl NP; glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

The event is "bubbling" to the parent `a` you need to use stopPropagation:

```
$('.delete_img').click(function(event) {
    alert("You dirty rat");
    event.stopPropagation();

});
```

Docs here -> http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/